# How do I pass parameters using redirector helper in Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework

Is it possible to pass parameters ($_POST or $_GET) with redirectory helper in Zend Framework? The following code redirect to index action of current controller, but I would like to pass some parameters to it as well.

```
$this->_helper->redirector("index");
```

Zend Documenataion does not say anything about it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Of course.  This is a code sample from the [Action Helpers documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html) (see the `Redirector` section, about 2/3 of the way down the page.)  You may need to grab a reference to the redirector helper and call one of the `goto*` methods like this code is doing.

```
class ForwardController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    /**
     * Redirector - defined for code completion
     *
     * @var Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector
     */
    protected $_redirector = null;

    public function init()
    {
        $this->_redirector = $this->_helper->getHelper('Redirector');
    }

    public function myAction()
    {
        /* do some stuff */

        // Redirect to 'my-action' of 'my-controller' in the current
        // module, using the params param1 => test and param2 => test2
        $this->_redirector->gotoSimple('my-action',
                                       'my-controller',
                                       null,
                                       array('param1' => 'test', 'param2' => 'test2'));
    }
}
```

Comment: @Andy Shellam // ah! How could I miss that! Thank you a lot!

Comment: The Action Helpers documentation referenced above is returning a 404  try this instead for version 1.12 - https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html

Comment: I use Zend 3.0.0, and my param order is redirector(module, action, controller, params)

Answer (score 8):

Pass an array as 4th parameter:

```
$this->_helper->redirector('action', 'controller', 'module', array('param1' => 'value1'));
```

Comment: what is the "module" parameter you use?

Comment: @softwareplay Name of the module you are using, if there is no module, I think you should set it empty. http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/modules.html